# TF Served Model Over Docker Missing Model Information, Returns 404 If Requested

Tags: python, docker, rest, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a trained model I am trying to deploy an image classifier through tensorflow serving in a Docker container. When I run my python code to request over REST I get a 404 response. The request looks as so:

```
json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/models/model_name:predict', data=data)
json_response.raise_for_status()

prediction = json_response.json()['predictions'][0]
print(prediction)
```

Upon inspection of the model information using curl, I get this in response:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Not Found</H1>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I followed the instructions from the [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) website on serving with docker and had no errors during the setup.

I believe it may have something to do with the way that I saved my model, since examples in the tf_serving guide worked, but I had used the SavedModel format as outlined on [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker) the code for which is here:

```
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
save_path = os.path.join(tmpdir, "model_name/1/")

print(list(model.signatures.keys()))  # ["serving_default"]

infer = model.signatures["serving_default"] # 5 classes
print(infer.structured_outputs)

tf.saved_model.save(model, save_path)
```

The print statements for the prior code:

```
['serving_default']
{'dense_2': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_2')}
```

In the tensorflow SavedModel guide it shows the structured output having the name "predictions", which may be part of the issue.

For reference, I am using transfer learning from a frozen MobileNetV2, with a few added layers.

I am fairly new to both Tensorflow and Tensorflow Serving, so please forgive me if this is a simple issue i may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

How did you start up your serving? Make sure the model name in your post request is the same to the name in model config.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."